# Android, Icon Templates Pack, where are the icons?

Tags: android, templates, icons, pack

I downloaded the templates pack from following link.
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#templatespack

When I open the psd files I see templates (backgrounds) but not the "Standard Menu Icons" displayed on many sites.

Where can I find these icons?

Answer (score 11):

> When I open the psd files I see templates (backgrounds) but not the "Standard Menu Icons" displayed on many sites.

As the documentation states:

> The Android Icon Templates Pack is a collection of template designs, textures, and layer styles that make it easier for you to create icons that conform to the guidelines given in this document

You will notice that the name is the "Icon *Templates* Pack", not the "Icon Pack".

> Where can I find these icons?

They are in your SDK, in `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/.../data/res`, where `$ANDROID_HOME` is wherever you installed the SDK and where `...` is some Android version.

Comment: I've been looking for these PNGs for quite a while!